# Fast marginalizations of a large Probability Mass Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, time-complexity

I will explain my problem through a simple example.

Imagine that I am given a probability mass function over a system of 10 3-states discrete random variables ($V_1,V_2,...,V_{10}$). So, I have $3^{10}=59049$ values stored in a computer memory.

I need to compute a set of marginal distributions from this big one. For instance $\{V_1,V_4\},\{V_1,V_6\},\{V_3\},\{V_3,V_6,V_8\}, ...$

How can I do it with a minimal number of additions ?
For instance I can marginalize both $\{V_1,V_2\}$ and $\{V_1\}$ with $3^{10}$ addition each. But, if I use the first result to compute the second, it will require only $3^2$ addition.

Another less trivial example, if I need $\{V_1,V_2\}$, $\{V_2,V_3\}$ and $\{V_1,V_3\}$, I can compute $\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}$  ($3^{10}$ additions) then get my results through eliminating an extra variable ($2^3$ additions each).

Which algorithm can be used in the general case ?

Some easy results :

if $V_i$ is never used, I can marginalize it out once and for all.

if some subset to marginalize S is included into another subset T, I can easily compute S from T.

I have not gone very far from those trivial simplifications...

Comment: It all depends on *how* the joint distribution is represented.  For instance, if you are given its distribution function (defined as $F(v_1,\ldots,v_{10})=\Pr(V_1\le v_1,\cdots,V_{10}\le v_{10})$), you can just read the marginals directly from it with no calculations at all.

Comment: I understand. It is smart. But, your structure will require $4^{10}$ values. We are currently using this method to compute all marginalizations through using an extra-dimension for all variable. But, it is costly as we start with the joint distribution stored in extension.

Comment: I believe it will require only $3^{10}$ values, because all other values are implicitly given by the laws of probability.

Comment: Oh you're right... So how many additions do I need to build your representation from the classical joint ? By analogy, I think we can build it by adding (1,?,?, ... ?) to (2,?,?, ... ?) then (2, ?,?,...?) to (3,?,?, ... ,?) then (?,1,?,..., ?) to (?,2, ?,..., ?), etc... that would be $10.2.3^9$ additions

Comment: If by "classical joint" you mean the *probability mass function,* then you will need $3^{10}-1$ additions, because there are $3^{10}$ numbers to specify and the only guaranteed relation among them is that they sum to unity.

Comment: Yes I meant probability mass function. It is clear that there are at least $3^{10}-1$ additions. But I don't see how we can devise an algorithm that uses exactly that number of additions. My proposed algorithm is less efficient.

Comment: I believe that if you visit the support of the distribution in lexicographic order, you can construct the distribution function from the pmf as a sequence of $3^{10}-1$ additions (of which the last will necessarily yield the value $1$).

Comment: brillant! Mathematically it is clearly the answer to my question as it is as cheap as any marginalization.

Comment: I am willing to write an answer to my question with the solution you proposed but only in case you have not the intention or time to do it yourself.

Comment: The problem we have discussed in the comments isn't the one you have posted in your question.  The question suggests you have a set of marginals you want to compute.  Given any such set, there typically is a more efficient way to obtain *just* those marginals from the probability mass function.

Comment: Well, whatever the algorithm, each value in my data needs to be added at least once because it influences any marginalization. So, I need at least $3^{10}-1$ additions. Your method requires that number of additions and leads to a very fast method to obtain any marginalization. To be exact, your method provides marginalized distributions represented as distribution functions, that need to be transformed if we want pfm. Maybe that is where there remains some optimisation. Is it your point?

Comment: well, well, well, it seems I was convinced too fast. I don't think we can construct the distribution function with $3^{10}-1$ additions. 
As an example, for binaries variable, I can not get $F(0,...,0,1,1)$ through the addition of $PMF(0,...,0,1,1)$ and an already calculated value.

Comment: That's not true: just as in one dimension, the distribution function is a cumulative sum of the PMF values -- you just have to do the summing correctly.  My previous point, though, is that this may be overkill if you need just a subset of the marginals.

Comment: Just try with 3 binary variables. You will see that you can not get each value with a single  addition. F(0,1,1)=pmf(0,0,0)+pmf(0,0,1)+pmf(0,1,0)+pmf(0,1,1), for instance, cannot be obtained with a single addition of terms from the pmf or the distribution function.

Comment: You're right -- even with two binary variables the problem becomes evident, because if the individual probabilities are $a,b,c,d$ then the values of the distribution function are $a,a+b,a+c,a+b+c+d.$ I apologize for misleading you.

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, you have made me discovered nice properties of the Distribution Function.